# task scheduling is not working even manually

Tags: laravel, task, scheduled-tasks

I wrote a task schedule in laravel. when i run the command

> php artisan schedule:run

it's not doing the task and it says no scheduled commands are ready to run. here is my task:

```
$schedule->call(function () {
    $now = new \DateTime();
        $premiums = User::where('account_type' , 'premium')->get();
        foreach ($premiums as $user){
            $user->account_type = 'basic';
            $user->save();
            $pr_time = new \DateTime($user->premium_time);
            if ($pr_time < $now ){
                $user->account_type = 'basic';
                $user->save();
            }
        }
})->hourly();
```

this code is in the ***protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)*** function.
what is wrong?

Comment: Well, you have it defined hourly, it would have to be run at the turn of the hour.

Comment: YES. that was the problem!. I thought the timing is not matter if i run it manually. thanks.

Comment: There's no difference in running it manually.  Artisan wouldn't know if you're calling schedule:run from the cron or from your shell..\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hourly() means running every hour at the turn of the hour (0 minute)

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling#schedule-frequency-options

schedule:run isn't meant to be run manually, it's meant to run every minute as a cronjob.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling#introduction